# js: checkbox of cloned object has no property checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, clone, attr

firstly, im sorry, i dont know how to put my question differently...

Imagine a form for customer orders with several order items.

To handle the form easier and faster the capability of copying an order item is given. This happens with the clone function and works. Some onclick properties must be changed therfore of the cloned object. For instance:

```
// tr is an tr element of a table
$(":input[type=checkbox]", tr).each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("onclick").click(function() {
        func($(this));
    });
});
```

The Function:

```
function func(chkbx)
{
    if (chkbx.checked) {
        // do stuff...
    } else {
        // do other stuff...
    }
}
```

Now the problem:
When the function is called by the origin tr-object everything works fine, but when the function is called by the cloned/copied tr it always goes into the else-branch.

I checked the passed object, certainly. Passed from the origin tr-object it's an HTMLInputElement as expected, but from the cloned one its a "normal" object. The strange thing is when i check both if they've got the "checked" property, none of them have it...

I just want the function to work properly for the cloned object, too..

I hope that somebody can help and everybody does understand me :D
thanks

---

update: the problem was solved with this:

```
$(chkbx).prop("checked")
```

instead of

```
chkbx.checked
```

but i wonder why the attr() function did result in an undefined?

Comment: Cange `chkbx.checked` to `chkbx.prop('checked')`

Comment: i did, but: TypeError: chkbx.prop is not a function

Comment: try just `$(chkbx).prop('checked')` then.

Comment: oh yeah, its a jquery function! thank you very much! that helped, but i wonder why the attr() function did not work...